# Meteor ubuntu startup exception error "watch ENOSPC"

Tags: ubuntu, meteor

I have an error on my meteor app witch occur immediatly after startup, that says :

```
=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/

/home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/run.js:425
    throw e;
          ^
Error: watch ENOSPC
    at errnoException (fs.js:806:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:837:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:861:11)
    at _.extend._startDirectoryWatches (/home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/watch.js:438:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend._startDirectoryWatches (/home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/watch.js:422:7)
    at new Watcher (/home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/watch.js:294:8)
    at exports.run.startWatching (/home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/run.js:481:15)
    at /home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/run.js:613:5
    at exports.inFiber (/home/<me>/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12)
```

I just have to re-start meteor and it is starting normally.

I'm on ubuntu 12.10, Meteor 0.6.5.1, and packages installed are the following :

```
insecure
preserve-inputs
jquery
http
standard-app-packages
oauth2
accounts-base
oauth
service-configuration
accounts-ui
random
accounts-oauth
accounts-google
```

Do anyone have an idea  ?

Thanks a lot
Philippe

Comment: I found a lead after some search : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc. I've tried the solution with the max inotify change and for now it seems to be working. I'm trying out for a little bit more before closing the question.

Comment: Hi check the below this . This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc

Answer (score 6):

Run this command

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

This will increase quantity of watched files setting for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The error `ENOSPC` means that there isn't enough space on your disk for meteor to run. While i'm not absolutely certain it is the issue it might be something to do with space or permissions.

Have a look with `df` to see what you have free, or delete some files if this is the issue.

Comment: thanks ! I did not know what the exact error was. I have check my disks but I have plenty of space left on it so it must be something else.