# Yeoman grunt server / grunt test troubles

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I'm playing around with yeoman
when I run

**grunt server**

I've got

*An error occurred while processing a template*

and when I run

**grunt test**

I can see

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux)]: Connected on socket 9kllv8fL_YVXKXD422aQ
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.2 secs / 0.035 secs)
```

but not the app up and running
so I'm wondering what's wrong

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which generator, what option, what versions of all the tools.

Comment: found the fix for the first http://stackoverflow.com/a/17437601