# Grunt server error, EMFILE

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Whenever I do "grunt server" it automatically gives me this error:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: EMFILE, too many open files
```

and next this:

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
```

This usual fix I've seen on the web is changing the name as shown bellow:

```
grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['jshint', 'uglify']);

grunt.registerTask('myuglify', ['jshint', 'uglify']);
```

Although my problem cannot be fixed with such method because I'm not using the same name as the task.

My gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'styles/css/main.css': 'styles/sass/main.scss'
      }
    }
  }

  ,watch: {
    options:{livereload:true},
    sass:{
        files:'styles/sass/*.scss',
        tasks:'sass'
        }
    },

    express:{
        all:{
            options:{
                port:9000,
                hostname:'localhost',
                bases:'.',
                livereload:true

            }

        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass'])
grunt.registerTask('server',['express','watch'])

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you have `livereload` both in `express` and `watch` configurations? Is this intentional?

Comment: Yeah, it was. Cause I want it to livereload. That's what the tutorials say

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this time-wasting error today, and the solution on the GitHub repository did not work for me. After searching for this issue in relation to the `process.nextTick` deprecation warning, I came to the conclusion that running a task dependent on a watched file/glob is a potential cause.

Here's the Gruntfile for my website:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            dev: {
                files: ['**/*.js', 'public/stylesheets/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['express:dev'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        },
        express: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    script: 'server.js',
                    node_env: 'development'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['express:dev', 'watch']);
};
```

I resolved the issue by removing js files from my `watch` task, which restarts Express. The below configuration of the aforementioned task works fine for me:

```
watch: {
    dev: {
        files: ['public/stylesheets/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['express:dev'],
        options: {
            spawn: false
        }
    }
},
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23900011/1114123) provides a similar fix. Interestingly, I've never encountered this problem on my Ubuntu machine; it happened on my MacBook today when I cloned my repository.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me when i typed

```
sudo grunt serve
```

possibly another solution. just increase increase read file limit.
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#how-do-i-fix-the-error-emfile-too-many-opened-files

```
ulimit -n 10480
```