# ENOSPC error when deploying Meteor 1.3 app to Bluemix

Tags: node.js, meteor, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Meteor 1.3 was released a few days ago.

Deployment using `cf push` of Meteor 1.3 apps to IBM Bluemix may fail with ENOSPC error. It appears that only simple Meteor 1.3 apps deploy successfully, as only after removing many packages or files (or creating a new app without adding many packages) it works.

ENOSPC means no space left or the number of files watched has reached the maximum allowed.

I think the latter may be the case. A solution for Node.JS apps is to increase the limit as described in [Node.JS Error: ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc):

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

However an attempt to use sudo in Bluemix returns

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

A GitHub issue was created in the cf-meteor-buildpack repository that show a number of other people experiencing the same problem:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack/issues/20

How can Meteor 1.3 apps be successfully deployed to Bluemix?

**Update:**
I have found the point at which just adding one more package to the app and deploying it causes the ENOSPC error. Without that package, the app deploys and runs successfully and the total disk usage as shown in the Bluemix Dashboard is just **220.1 MB**. The default disk quota is 1 GB, so there is actually plenty of free space left. Therefore it is likely that the error is caused by *exceeding a maximum number of files*, not the disk quota being reached.

Just to be sure, I increased the disk quota to 2 GB via Cloud Foundry's manifest.yml and the ENOSPC error still occurred when I added the extra package. Without the package, the disk usage is "220.1 MB / 2 GB" in the dashboard. That package (kadira:flow-router) is very unlikely to need 1.8 GB of space.

Meteor 1.3 creates many more files than previous versions because there is a new node-modules directory into which many individual Node.js modules are installed.

To check the value of max_user_watches, I added this line to the buildpack script:
`cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`
The result shown is `8192`.

I then added this line to attempt to change the value:
`echo 32768 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`
The result is `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches: Permission denied`.

Is it possible to increase the maximum number of allowed file watches via Cloud Foundry? The operating system is Linux.

Comment: In the cf-meteor-buildpack issue you reference, some people report it working after switching to version 1.3.1. Are you still seeing the ENOSPC error?

Comment: The ENOSPC error still occurs with the latest version of Meteor, which is now 1.3.2.4.