# Visual Studio Code won't open via command line

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code on my machine.
It worked pretty well just after the installation.

But since I restarted my computer, it just won't open when I type the command 'code' in my terminal.

When I type the command to open Visual Studio, nothing happens.
But if I type

```
which code
```

it returns me `/usr/bin/code`, so the program is installed. The editor won't open even if I use sudo.

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and I installed the program using the `.deb package offered` [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/?utm_expid=101350005-21.ckupCbvGQMiML5eJsxWmxw.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F)
Any suggestions?

**edit**

I tried to create a symlink to the installation path. But now I got errors:

```
andre@andre-Lenovo-G40-80:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/code/code /usr/local/bin/code
andre@andre-Lenovo-G40-80:~$ which code
    /usr/local/bin/code
andre@andre-Lenovo-G40-80:~$ code
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
Error: watch /home/andre/.config/Code/User ENOSPC
at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1323:19)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1351:11)
at r.e.registerWatchers (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:8:16692)
at r.e (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:8:15951)
at new r (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:8:19184)
at v (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:15395)
at t._createInstance (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:7:23640)
at t._createAndCacheServiceInstance (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:7:24615)
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the negative vote, so I can learn what I did wrong here, please

Comment: thank you Brian. Can you upvote the question, so it will not be ignored?

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/616075/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu The answer mentions running from terminal. You've probably seen it already anyhow

Comment: thank you for the link @BrianB. I created the symlink, but now I'm getting errors when trying to open the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably hit the limit on `inotify` watches.  Notice this error:

```
Error: watch /home/andre/.config/Code/User ENOSPC
```

Then see the question [Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve).  The essence of the solution is to increase the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` system control value.