# Why won't this Angular2 JavaScript Sample App Launch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to install [this github sample Angular2 app written in JavaScript](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter), but the app fails to lead in the browser.  I am including a print screen below that shows the FireFox console reporting it was not able to find `boot.css`.  **What specific steps or changes do I need to make in order for the example app to successfully launch?**

Per the instructions at the link above, I typed the following into the CentOS 7 terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter.git
cd angular2-esnext-starter
npm install

gulp serve
```

The terminal then printed the following:

```
[user@localhost angular2-esnext-starter]$ gulp serve
[14:50:17] Using gulpfile ~/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/gulpfile.js
[14:50:17] Starting 'serve'...
[14:50:17] Starting 'clean'...
[14:50:17] Finished 'clean' after 38 ms
[14:50:17] Starting 'client-build'...
[14:50:17] Starting 'client-copy'...
[14:50:17] Starting 'client-stylesheet'...
[14:50:17] Starting 'livereload'...
[14:50:17] Finished 'livereload' after 2.43 ms
[14:50:18] Finished 'client-stylesheet' after 808 ms
[14:50:19] Finished 'client-copy' after 1.61 s
[14:50:23] Finished 'client-build' after 5.94 s
[14:50:23] Starting 'server-start'...
[14:50:23] Finished 'server-start' after 1.36 ms
[14:50:23] Finished 'serve' after 5.98 s
[14:50:23] [nodemon] 1.9.2
[14:50:23] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[14:50:23] [nodemon] watching: /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/server/**/*
[14:50:23] [nodemon] starting `node server/index.js`
[14:50:24] [nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch /home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2-esnext-starter/server/config.js ENOSPC
```

And then I got the following in the browser:

[image]

To confirm that I had at least version 4+ of Node.js installed, I then typed the following, and got the following response:

```
[user@localhost angular2-esnext-starter]$ node --version
v5.12.0
```

Comment: Note: The application needs at least Node 4+ installed. ?

Comment: It says `ENOSPC` right at the end, have a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius I just added a note to the end of the OP showing that Node.js version 5.12.0 is installed.

Comment: @chrki  OK, but this is on a virtual machine whose disk size can grow arbitrarily large.  And the host OS has almost a terabyte of empty space on its real hard drive.

Comment: @FirstOfMany Read beyond the 1st answer, it seems to be not just a hard disk space problem

Comment: @chrki  The problem was solved by typing `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`.  If you want to write an answer that explains what that command is doing, you would be improving upon the link you posted, and I would mark it as +1 accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right at the end of your logs: `ENOSPC`

According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc) this can be caused by either having not enough disk space, or by exhausting the number of files a process can watch.

In your case it's likely that the nodejs process has reached the default number of files it can watch. In the `gulpfile.js` settings file the  `livereload` command is configured - it "watches" the directory and its files and triggers a reload when something changes. Although there are only 83 files in the repository it's possible that all the installed dependencies (found inside the package.json file, installed via `npm install`) make it reach the file watch limit.