# Gulp gives this error "events.js: 141 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

When I run the command gulp, I get the following error.
I am using Elementary Loki and Node 4.2.6. All the other commands are wroking fine:

- npm install
- bower install
- gulp build

```
anshul@anshul-HP-Notebook:~/Downloads/fivevolts$ gulp
[16:05:40] Using gulpfile ~/Downloads/fivevolts/gulpfile.js
[16:05:40] Starting 'usemin'...
[16:05:40] Starting 'copy-bower_fonts'...
[16:05:40] Starting 'custom-images'...
[16:05:40] Starting 'custom-js'...
[16:05:40] Starting 'custom-less'...
[16:05:40] Starting 'custom-templates'...
[16:05:40] Starting 'webserver'...
[16:05:41] Finished 'webserver' after 139 ms
[16:05:41] Starting 'livereload'...
[16:05:41] Finished 'livereload' after 12 ms
[16:05:41] Starting 'watch'...
[16:05:41] 'watch' errored after 10 ms
[16:05:41] Error: watch /home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/src/img/ ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1234:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1262:11)
    at Gaze._watchDir (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:289:30)
    at /home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:358:10
    at iterate (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
    at Object.forEachSeries (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:66:3)
    at Gaze._initWatched (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:354:10)
    at Gaze.add (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:177:8)
    at new Gaze (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:74:10)
[16:05:41] Server started http://localhost:8888
[16:05:41] LiveReload started on port 35729
[16:05:41] Finished 'custom-less' after 201 ms
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/dist ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1234:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1262:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:407:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:455:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/anshul/Downloads/fivevolts/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:460:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I don't think the error is in the code, as I tried to run gulp on some other project codes that were working fine earlier, are now getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.JS Error: ENOSPC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc)

Comment: can be due to maximum files that can be watched. posting your gulp file can help propably too.
Here is some similar problem: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/217

Answer (score 0):

This happens when multiple applications trying to access the same port, Its always FIFO. Check your gulp toolkit port and try again.