# Error calling Appregistry.runApplication in react-native and Android

Tags: react-native

I got similar problem like this question:

[Error calling Appregistry.runApplication in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744156/error-calling-appregistry-runapplication-in-react-native/43745684)

Comment: I had almost the same problem you currently have a few days ago. For me it was a real device.
From all my research, the solution that worked for me is the following :
When you launch your app by typing `react-native run-android`, the error appears.So, reach your directory containing "adb.exe" ( for me it was C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\ )
open a terminal from here. And type `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
Then, by reloading the app on the phone, it should work.I hope this will help you !! ( if not, shame on me )Cheers ;)Through this process i got my solution

Comment: Please edit you post to make it readable.

Comment: Ramcoder, your comment makes it seem you have solved this. Why not add an answer to the other question? There is no value in duplicating the question, especially with so little context.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525431/getting-error-closed-twice-on-adb-reverse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle