# Error calling RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit in ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native

I am begginer in ReactNative ... After install the first project in my Device This error was displayed:

> Error calling RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit

What is the problem ? [image]

Comment: I am getting the same error.someone help us out

Comment: I am getting the same error if I run application via android studio but if I run react-native run-android it works perfectly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From all my research, the solution that worked for me is the following :

When you launch your app by typing `react-native run-android`, the error appears.

So, reach your directory containing "adb.exe" ( for me it was C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\ )

open a terminal from here. And type `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Then, by reloading the app on the phone, it should work.

Comment: after type : "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 ", its shows "error : closed " !

Comment: I feel like I've already seen this answer before... x) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744156/error-calling-appregistry-runapplication-in-react-native/43789531#43789531

Comment: I am not using Windows, so the accepted answer was not for me. However, this answer worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: It helped me, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

finally, I found the solution and it's working for me now.

if you are using ReactNative in windows you must turn off the `firewall` then it will work!

Comment: @RohanGala In my case, it worked after turning off the firewall

Comment: @Mohsenmokhtari what about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I resolved it.

Terminate your metro bundler > react-native link > react-native run-ios

It was not bundling because of some errors which are not showing into the emulator but just bundling was failed. After I re-bundled the package from starting, the error was resolved.