# How to run React Native project on Emulator in WebStorm

Tags: android, react-native, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm IDE for develop my React Native Android project. I have followed these steps in their [website](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/). But there is no way to connect with Emulator. When I run the project it show bellow error.

[image]

---

**Update**

[image]

[image]

Comment: For android you specifically have to run emulator first before runing project.

Comment: yes i have run emulator from command line.but this error showing

Comment: is realm linked properly? Can you try running: react-native link realm.

Comment: now Emulator is runnig.what i have did is 1) run emulator from cmd.[run from cmd](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html). 2) set port to emulator (emulator -port 8081 -avd Nexus_5X_API_23).now emulator is running but showing red error on emulator `Error calling Appregistry.runApplication` . i have updated my post

Comment: I got some issue in windows. What I did was I first ran npm start first to start  the packager and then I ran react-native run-android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744156/error-calling-appregistry-runapplication-in-react-native#44035335

Answer (score 0):

There could be always something missing when you trying to use a library etc. My recommendation is npm uninstall realm and install again and check android directory if it is not realm linked decent, relink again manually or with following code react-native link realm.

edit for updated post: try `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` .  If you have remotely debugging problem then try `adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082`

Comment: i have tried it.in my terminal showing `CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip
`.also `WARNING: Requested adb port (8082) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details`.see update

Comment: i have solve this.solution is start in another port `
react-native start --port 9988`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create the react-native app with `create-react-native-app` and open created the folder in WebStorm rather than creating an app with WebStorm.

It may be caused by incompatibility of `react-native` version that is using in WebStorm and your Android Studio version. Also, I recommend using stable Node JS version.

`create-react-native-app` is the best way to create an app for today because it uses expo kit that provides you the wireless connection between your server and developing an app on your phone. It always uses the latest version of `react` and `react-native` that provides you stability versions and doesn't depend on WebStorm at all.

Follow [this steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) to create a new app with expo kit.

Comment: I don't see anything about app creation in the question.