# Why does standalone react-native app doesn't work but works well on Expo Client? How to fix it?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a react native app, things work fine on expo client. But I am getting: 'Uncaught Error: Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication' in the log after splash screen.

I have added AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', ()=> App) and this works through Expo client. I was creating the SDK through expo build:android.

```
{
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-material-cards": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "typescript": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json?

Comment: Edited with package.json

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Can you post your .babelrc as well?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find it. Where could it be?

Comment: If it exists, it is in the home folder. Do you see any file whose name is starting with '.'? If not, maybe your hidden files are not shown.

Comment: It does not exist.

Comment: I see that you got help already... Good luck!

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: No idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When you entered 'expo init appname', is the name you entered 'main'?

```js
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => componentName)
```

If not, refer to [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744156/error-calling-appregistry-runapplication-in-react-native?answertab=votes#tab-top)

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\`
open a terminal from here. And type `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: No, it wasn't 'main'. It was 'AwesomeProject'. I am sure the link confused me more. I started react-native or any app development 4 days back. So pardon my ignorance.

Comment: It's okay. Anyone can make that mistake.

Comment: What about in macOS?

Comment: If the path is not set, open `./bash_profile`  //  `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/UserId/library/android/sdk/tools:${PATH}:/Users/UserId/library/android/sdk/platform-tools`

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: you changed `Appname` and tried `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, but it didn't work out?

Comment: I am not using emulator. so that won't work anyway right?

Comment: If 'Expo' has been separated as 'react-native', it can only be run as an emulator.