# Nodemon internal watch failed error?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, nodemon

I don't know what happened but suddenly my Nodemon starting to show the error.

```
nikhil@nikhil-Lenovo-Z50-70:~/Desktop/dominos$ nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch /home/nikhil/Desktop/dominos 
ENOSPC
```

Even though after that my program runs fine. But when I close this project1 and runs another project2 on the same port then this error occurs

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1047:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1319:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1367:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1467:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nikhil/Desktop/dominos/server.js:533:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

And then my old project1 would remain open and my new project2 cannot be started until I manually kill the process.

Any idea why this is happening??

Comment: the port 3000 is already used by another process

Comment: Yes If I kill the process by using the Kill Command Then my projects run fine but this problem started to show from few days before that I was able to run the countless application with nodemon on the same port.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're on linux, the issue could be that you have too many open watchers.
Run this command:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

and try again.

Credit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc/32600959#32600959).

Answer (score 5):

In my case,

Error: [nodemon] Internal watch failed: EMFILE: too many open files, watch

Solution:

1. I close the vs code,
2. Reopen it, and solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me too. it was that simple!
Wasted one hour.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is occurring because already another process or terminal use your same port

kill all node by using following command

```
killall node
```

start nodemon by using following comand

```
nodemon server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error. Node worked, but not nodemon. All I did was:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

And it worked

Comment: helped me too, but in my case it was installed locally

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this issue and I have tried all the solutions mentioned above but the solution works for me is just close the IDE and restart again the IDE it will help me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurs because nodemon is not installed properly please follow the instructions:

- check your nodemon by using command `nodemon -v`.

> **version**:
> 2.0.22

- If you received nodemon version then it's working well otherwise use `npm install nodemon -g` command to install package.
- use `lsof -i -n -P | grep node` command to check your node.js running PORTS such as:

> **output**:
> `node      460517 adil   20u  IPv6 13299837      0t0  TCP *:3003 (LISTEN)`

- if you received then kill unusable running PORTS by using `kill -9 460517` command.
- Run `nodemon ./index.ts` or `npm start` command.

**Issue resolved.**