# How to develop Create React Native App without a network - using USB only

Tags: android, react-native, create-react-native-app

I would like to develop an app in Create React Native App in the environment where connecting from the Android device to the development server is not possible.

I have installed Android development tools on my laptop and the device is connected to it via USB. When I run `npm run android` everything starts correctly as it should, Expo is opened in the device but then it ends with an errors:

> Could not load exp://192.168.128.150:19000. Can't connect to internet. Please try again

Does this mean that I cannot use Create React Native app without network between the mobile device and the working computer ?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best solution, but it worked for me and i hope it'll be enough to help you out!

I was having the same problem and did the following:

1. Connected the device to the PC through the USB Port
2. Verified if it was authorized using `adb devices`
3. Disconnected the PC/Laptop from the internet
4. Ran `npm run android` with the device connected
5. Waited for the Javascript Bundle to be built
6. Reconnected the PC to the network after the application was running on the device

After that i could normally develop through the USB! Hope i've been of help!

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with that for last couple of days with my development environment on the virtualized Ubuntu 18.04. I have 2 interfaces on the guest machine (host-only as ens33, and bridge as ens39).

First of all I've installed `react-native-cli` to work on.

The steps I do to work only with USB cable (e.g. in VPN network with no chance to connect the device):

1. Bring all all interfaces listed in `etc/etc/interfaces` down. , e.g. `sudo ifdown ens33`. In my case only host-only is listed there so I can still work with the bridge interface.
2. Connect the device through USB port.
3. Run `adb usb` and then `adb devices`.
4. Just in case run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.
5. Run `react-native start --reset-cache` in one terminal. If you have an error with ENPOSC while starting Metro Bundler on 8081 port then follow the instructions here: [Node.JS Error: ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc/32600959#32600959).
6. In the second terminal run `react-native run-android`. If all things went good you should see "exp://127.0.0.1:19000" on the screen just under QR code and running app on the device.