# Starting with meanJS

Tags: mean-stack

I have a small problem to start meanJS following the installation with the generator YO. I can not solve my problem. Can someone help me ? Everything is well installed and when I run the command "npm start", that's what I have ...

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...

Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Warning: watch /home/ludo/workspace/lab/meanjs/mean/modules/core/server/views/ ENOSPC

Done, without errors.
[nodemon] 1.12.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: server.js config/**/*.js modules/*/server/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch /home/ludo/workspace/lab/meanjs/mean/server.js ENOSPC
(node:19618) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
```

Warning: (node:19618) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.

Comment: ENOSPC means "no space", make sure your filesystems aren't full.

Comment: Thank you @Mat for your answer. But I dont understand. Which file system would be full

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc) question.