# vue js app yarn serve is failing with exit code 1.?

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, yarnpkg

I am building frontend of a web app using vuejs. till yesterday my app was running fine but all of sudden today `yarn serve` command is throwing an error.

```
 Error: watch /home/abhey/Documents/abhey/astrix/astrix_final_project/ecommerceFrontend/public ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/abhey/Documents/abhey/astrix/astrix_final_project/ecommerceFrontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/abhey/Documents/abhey/astrix/astrix_final_project/ecommerceFrontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/abhey/Documents/abhey/astrix/astrix_final_project/ecommerceFrontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:232:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/abhey/Documents/abhey/astrix/astrix_final_project/ecommerceFrontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:414:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/abhey/Documents/abhey/astrix/astrix_final_project/ecommerceFrontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:462:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/abhey/Documents/abhey/astrix/astrix_final_project/ecommerceFrontend/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:467:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I did try to look into the documentation but it was of no use. I also tried to start a new project altogether but it was of no help. any suggestions?   if it's of any use I am using Linux Mint 19 as my os.

Comment: `ENOSPC` means there's no space left on the drive - Are you running low on disk space?

Comment: no not at all my disk is 30 percent up only and its the only application running along with my chrome browser...

Comment: Please see @Majed Fayazi's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I had the same problem with npm. 
You can try to clean the npm cache remove the node module folder and re install the dependencies try this code in your terminal.

```
    cd ~
    sudo rm -rf .npm 
    cd <package folder where node module exist> 
    npm cache clean 
    rm -rf node_modules
    npm install
```

try same logic with yarn it will solve your problem.