# Issue in `npm start` command in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, create-react-app

I am trying to install React.js. In this regard, I run `npm install -g create-react-app` and `create-react-app my-app`. Then I run the `npm start` command but I am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: I face a similar issue so instead of using npm I used yarn to install dependency and it solved my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc check this thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please delete folder node_modules and clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Also try remove package-json.lock file.

After this re-run your command.