# Ionic framework (events.js:183 ) Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

***When i used ionic serve it throws some error even though I tried many solutions like ([solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975596/events-js183-throw-er-unhandled-error-event),[solution 2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2922),[solution 3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2921)) but nothing was worked and i mentioned my error below***

```
 events.js:183
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

***I listed below my System and Ionic Information***

```
PS G:\Ionic\FabAppLatest> ionic info
√ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\Align Associate\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android broken
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 28 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```