# A day before it was working, but now 'yarn start' not working in ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu

I'm new in Ubuntu as well as in ReactJS. I worked with same command `yarn start` yesterday but today I'm doing same and its showing some errors in Ubuntu terminal.[image]

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Comment: `ENOSPC` error is that no space is available on the drive. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600959/5182917) answer to resolve it.

Comment: @nrgwsth yup its working, thank a lot.