# nodemon - Internal watch failed: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/user/Documents/github/sendMail-lib/3808.txt

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, server, nodemon

I am getting an error while running my server file using ***nodemon***. When I type the command `nodemon`, I get the following output.

```
[~/D/g/sendMail-lib|3.6.5]
‹master*› »»»» nodemon                                                0|15:35:32
[nodemon] 1.17.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/abdus/Documents/github/sendMail-lib/3808.txt'
[~/D/g/sendMail-lib|3.6.5]
‹master*› »»»»
```

**Additionally**, it creates almost 4000 blank text files(1.txt, 2.txt and so on).

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc) commands but the problem still persists.

I am on **Arch Linux** with **Node version 10.5.0**, **NPM version 6.1.0** and **Nodemon version 1.17.5**.

Just ask me if you need any more information.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 18-04, Node.js v10.6.0, nodemon 1.17.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Run nodemon as sudo.

```
$ sudo nodemon
```

Or

```
# nodemon
```

Most issues I run into with Arch are solved by just running as root. ;)

Comment: I'd strongly advise against running things as root, though.

Comment: This is useful. However as @awwright commented it is not recommended to run this as _root_. I'd upvote this if it includes the alternative to just give the right permissions to the folders|files as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/907#issuecomment-360385116).

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution for me (im using Fedora 30)

Answer (score 3):

This is effectively a rights problem, but you don't need to use sudo, just give the user that run nodemon the rights to write to the build directory

an exemple with permissive rights (we use nodemon, so I assume we are in dev)

```
sudo chmod a+rwX my-application-dir
```

Comment: I will check this method if I face this issue again. Thank you @Jo Takion

Answer (score 2):

I installed nodemon locally so, I created an "npm start" script and run it as root
like so: sudo npm start

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when trying to run `npm start` with a start script that looked like this:

"start": "nodemon server.js"

It seems that I had a global installation of `nodemon`, but not a local version in my project's `node_modules`.  Once I ran `npm install nodemon`, it installed it locally and worked without requiring root permissions.

nodemon: v1.18.5

OS: ubuntu 18.04