# npm start not working in react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am currently working on a react project and have already developed the basic components. Everything was working fine yesterday. Then I started a new react native project. After installing the project using create-react-native-app, the `npm start` command failed to start the server but it was working just fine for the react project.

I was using node 10.6 and npm 5.6. After reading some suggestions, I changed  node to v8.11 and npm to 6.2. After installing watchman and changing the inotify watches, I finally fot the native app to start.

Today, I tried to start the react project and the server is not starting.
This is what the terminal is displaying...

```
  Starting the development server...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/maneesh/source_code/react/ytc/public ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/maneesh/source_code/react/ytc/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/maneesh/source_code/react/ytc/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/maneesh/source_code/react/ytc/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/maneesh/source_code/react/ytc/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:407:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/maneesh/source_code/react/ytc/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:455:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/maneesh/source_code/react/ytc/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:460:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ytc@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ytc@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04 
node 8.11
npm 6.2

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Hi,
probably duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc/32600959#32600959) 
or look at [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2549)

Comment: Yes! The second link worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> You can run the below command to avoid ENOSPC:
>
> `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a
>   /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`
>
> For Arch Linux add this line to /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:
>
> `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`
>
> Finally, run:
>
> `sysctl --system`
>
> This will also persist across reboots.

Source: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Comment: Can you explain why this solves the original question? All you are doing here is creating a new project and starting it.

Comment: it worked for me ,i installed node js,after that i used node js command  prompt and npm install -g create-react-app ,then create-react-app my-app,then npm start,after all this i got this error ,then i used cd my-app,then npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 and finally npm start,it worked for me