# running vue documentation locally

Tags: vue.js

i was trying to run vuejs documentation offline (locally) and had no lack, it worked in the past but i don't know what i have done wrong.

i followed the steps on the following post
[hear](https://mjawaid.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/how-to-offline-access-to-vue-js-documentation/)

basically the steps are

1. install hexo-cli globally

   npm install hexo-cli --global
2. clone vuejs.org repository

   git clone https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org.git
3. install project dependencies

   cd vuejs.org && npm install
4. run local server using npm or hexo

   npm start

i keep gett

```
FATAL Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: http://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
Error: watch /vuejs.org/themes/vue/layout/icons/ltc.ejs ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1374:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1400:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/vuejs.org/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/vuejs.org/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/vuejs.org/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/vuejs.org/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/vuejs.org/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
```

Comment: Looks like ENOSPC error [means "No Space"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc), check that you have enough free disk space.

Comment: yes, that seems to be one of the problem thanks. the other being the watchers.

Answer (score 0):

You ran out of watchers. Proper solution would be to find out why that happened, however you can simply raise available amount of watchers.

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

or remove files that are watched but aren't needed, for example some unused templates or assets.

You can find more options here:
[Node.JS Error: ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc)