# BroccoliMergeTrees (TreeMerger (lint)): Expected Broccoli node, got [object Object] for inputNodes[1]

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frameworks, ember-data, ember-cli

I have started using ubuntu 18.04 and while setting up my ember dev environment, i have come across this issue. In other OS(Windows) my ember project is working fine, but in this OS,an error is thrown BroccoliMergeTrees (TreeMerger (lint)): Expected Broccoli node, got [object Object] for inputNodes[1]. I am not able to understand why it is happening. 
Ember Version: 1.13.15
Node Version: 6.11.2

Can any one Help me here?

> ErrorStack Trace!!: 
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pLYd.png

Comment: You might want to check your `ember-cli-build.js` file or `index.js`.
There error seems to come from this method:
https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/EmberApp.html#method_addonLintTree
So maybe you have a `postprocessTree` method that isn't working?

Either way, I'd suggest to use the latest stable Ember and Node version. If that's not an option, you might want to check if the node version is the same on Windows.

Btw. the NVM (node version manager) is a great tool for Ubuntu to switch node versions.

Comment: Thanks enspandi ! Yes I can't use other version of ember on this project. I also use NVM to switch node versions and i have tried it with several versions of node(also with same node as on windows) and the same error is thrown every time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was with "node_modules/brocolli-plugin". This module was different from that on windows which I was using before. So, what i did is that i replaced my brocolli-plugin folder in node_modules with the same, and then magically somehow it started working!!
What you  can do is if the project is running on someone else's system, try replacing ur brocolii plugin folder with those who have working ember server.
After that you will face some more issues, which you can google about. One of those is ENOSPC: and the solution is : [Node.JS Error: ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc)