# react-native cant run on android platform

Tags: facebook, api, react-native

I'm trying to run my react-native project on android phone... I follow all steps but when I type in this command `react-native start` I get:

> Scanning folders for symlinks in /var/www/html/laravelReact/testReact/node_modules (6ms)
>   Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.
>   Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to
>   close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer. 
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native 
>   Looking for JS files in
>   /var/www/html/laravelReact/testReact 
>   Metro Bundler ready.ERROR
>
> ERROR  watch
>   /var/www/html/laravelReact/testReact/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-sv
>   ENOSPC

Comment: what operating system are you using? Linux?

Comment: yes .. Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc/32600959#32600959

Comment: Else try ... in terminal go to directoy, then `cd android && gradlew clean` ....
`cd .. && react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

In cmd,in your project path, run `npm install` first,then `react-native run-android`