# Unable to start react-native start

Tags: android, react-native

**I'm getting below message from terminal while trying to run "react-native start" command.**

```
Loading dependency graph...internal/fs/watchers.js:170
    throw error;

Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/android/gradle'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:164:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1232:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:159:22)
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/sane/src/common.js:109:31)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at /home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at go$readdir$cb (/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:162:14)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

[First screenshot displays emulator screen when I run "$react-native run-android" cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuNgl.png)

[Second pic is screenshot when I reloaded the app by double pressing R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DegIC.png)

Comment: Your device doesn't have enough space to run the app. clear some data (free some memory) and run again

Comment: There is another post on this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve)

Answer (score 2):

> In android some time you need to first Start Metro Bundler manually!
>
> Start Metro Bundler directly in terminal

`react-native start`

> Now run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` in another tab

and yes if you getting some error like `Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/android/gradle' at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:164:26) at Object.watch (fs.js:1232:11) at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:159:22) at Walker. (/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/sane/src/common.js:109:31) at Walker.emit (events.js:182:13) at /home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16 at go$readdir$cb (/home/junior/ReactNative/ToDoList/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:162:14) at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)` then you need to delete your current emulator and create new one with additinal spaces,

and if you getting anyting wrong in your terminal then you can reset your npm data as well

> Clean cache

`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install -g react-native` and try afterwards