# npm test give me the ENOSPC error, but works with sudo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

So I'm just learning and while following a tutorial which asks to install `npm install --save-dev enzyme@3.8.0 enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.7.1`.

When I run `npm test`, I get the following output:

```
(testdriven) linux@ubuntu:~/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client$ npm install --save-dev enzyme@3.8.0 enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.7.1
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.0.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ enzyme@3.8.0
+ enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.7.1
updated 2 packages and audited 36587 packages in 21.377s
found 0 vulnerabilities

(testdriven) linux@ubuntu:~/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client$ npm test

> client@0.1.0 test /home/linux/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client
> react-scripts test

fs.js:1384
    throw error;
    ^

Error: watch /home/linux/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client/node_modules/.cache ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/linux/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:175:20)
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/home/linux/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client/node_modules/sane/src/common.js:116:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at /home/linux/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at go$readdir$cb (/home/linux/testdriven/testdriven-app/services/client/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:162:14)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Yet, when I run it as `sudo npm test`, I get the expected result.

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Reading other posts, I learned that `ENOSPC` is a no space error. Which is not the case, I have 70GB free.

Is it a permission error? I manually checked the permissions and did not come across anything.

Any suggestion to figure this out would be great. I can continue with the tutorial for now but it would be nice to know what causes this and fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found it.

The reason why I did not see the complete error previously is that I was using terminal inside VS Code. When I ran it from a regular terminal I saw the complete error which this explains it, along with the workaround.

`"Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" (error ENOSPC)`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

Answer (score 0):

[*The fact that you are out of watches does not mean that its VSCode's fault.*]

### Let's fix it

- Open a new terminal.
- You can get your current inotify file watch limit by executing:

  ```
    $ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
  ```
- You can set a new limit temporary with:

  ```
    $ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288

    $ sudo sysctl -p
  ```

  return:

  ```
    fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
  ```
- If you like to make your limit permanent, use:

  ```
    $ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf


    $ sudo sysctl -p
  ```

[source](https://gist.github.com/iamfoysal/e3e840b46a1a32d2e42e2ca9c6d20348)