# events.js:183 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: watch /home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/assets ENOSPC

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I add Image to Asset folder in my project and try to excute npm start in terminal I got this error

I am working on ubuntu
I tried == "killall node" in terminal
I removed the file I insert into asset folder and still not working
I restarted the computer

```
Starting the development server...
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/assets ENOSPC
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/mihre/Desktop/React/latest/lc-net-front-end-website/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-redux-saga-boilerplate@2019.2.0 start: `node tools/start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-saga-boilerplate@2019.2.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mihre/.npm/_logs/2019-05-24T19_09_09_245Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow. For us to be able to help you, please provide a [mcve] for us to test/work through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)