# getting an error when starting npm server

Tags: reactjs

[image]I had my app working nicely before I made changes to public/index.html file to change the favicon icon. At that time it did not give any error but next day when I started the npm server again, I got this. Now my other react apps are also showing the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve)

Comment: Solved it. I got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the node_modules folder and install again.

```
npm install
```

make sure to clearing npm cached files too.