# How to solve issue when running new project in react native in android device

Tags: react-native

I'm beginner for react native,I'm create a new project in react-native some time working fine,many time showing following errors in emulator or device,please help to fix the issue,
!http://prntscr.com/o9zv7t

these error to occur many time ,I dnt know what is the problem 
!http://prntscr.com/oa016k

The following version are installed  React native

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.10
node v9.11.2
I'm using ubuntu os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error occurs when your device lost connection from the system for that you just need to run `react-native run-android` and the connection will establish again.

The second error you just need to expand the limit of max_user_watches by running this command:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

for more detailed info go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve/32600959#32600959)