# Error : index.android.bundle (run 'react-native' start)

Tags: react-native

Firstly react-native install and then create a project, this problem are created to the run time in android phone.

I got this error :

> Error : index.android.bundle (run 'react-native' start)

[image]
[image]

Comment: try to run react-native run-android again

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your device lost connection from the system for that you just need to run `react-native run-android` and the connection will establish again.

For more and detailed info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869396/how-to-solve-issue-when-running-new-project-in-react-native-in-android-device/56869738#56869738)