# React app is not running in the browser. How to resolve this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Starting the development server...

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/test/Documents/test/public ENOSPC


      at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
        at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
        at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
        at createFsWatchInstance (/home/test/Documents/test/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
        at setFsWatchListener (/home/test/Documents/test/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
        at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/oxss-006/Documents/test/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
        at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/test/Documents/test/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
        at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/test/Documents/test/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
        at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/test/Documents/test/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2019-09-23T04_38_51_220Z-debug.log
```

When starting npm i am getting error. Its not running in the browser. How to resolve this? If anyone knows please answer this.

```
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Did you mean http://localhost3000.org/?
Search Google for localhost 3000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am using these versions
`node v -v8.10.0`
`npm  - 6.11.3`

Thanks.

Comment: you created project using create-react-app ?

Comment: Try running watch command all over again.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar yes. via terminal

Comment: @Emily, its local space issue, run it on terminal===> echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=999999 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p    <====      and put user_watches=999999.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar. Thanks now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=999999 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
>   && sudo sysctl -p

Your watch is over, watch are for reloading the app whenever there is something change in code.

Comment: I am not changed any code. Once i created react app .not able to access in the browser. Its says localhost refused to connect.

Comment: just fire this above command in the terminal and restart your react app

Answer (score -1):

Run the below command to avoid ENOSPC:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

For Arch Linux add this line to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Then execute:

```
sysctl --system
```

Here is the reference link where I found the solution.
https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details
[Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve)

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: tried above command via terminal. But not getting any response. Still same issue.