# Error running npm run serve on new vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, frontend, vue-cli

I made this:

```
vue create myfirstapp 
atom (for open my editor)
cd myfirst app
npm run serve
```

and I get this

```
> myfirstapp@0.1.0 serve /home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
10% building 2/2 modules 0 activeevents.js:196
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/public'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (internal/fs/watchers.js:168:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1351:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:5)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:5) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/public',
  filename: '/home/paolinsky/Documentos/vueBasico/fazt/myfirstapp/public'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myfirstapp@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myfirstapp@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/paolinsky/.npm/_logs/2019-12-15T15_13_50_223Z-debug.log
```

This always happen in all my vue projects, included the new ones.

My versions are: 
npm: 6.13.4
node: v13.3.0

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on an asus vivobook laptop
4gb ram, Intel core I3 7th gen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this same problem recently. I solved it like this:

```bash
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Comment: It modifies the maximum number of files that can be watched. I don't know exactly why it's an issue to begin with. I assume `npm run serve` is watching the entire directory. And if you're using **npm**, that's **A LOT** of files because of the node_modules directory.

Comment: Thank you, you save my life jajaja