# Unexpected error while installing dependencies using yarn

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am getting below error while installing dependencies using yarn,

```
"ENNOSPC: no space left on device, copyfile 'c:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\V6\\npm-react-16.13.1-245677gb7..-integrity\\node_modules\\react\\umd\\react.profiling.min.js'
```

->

```
'c:\\users\\...\\MyProject\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\sp-webpart-workbench\\node_modules\\@fluentui\\react-window-provider\\node_modules\\react\\umd\\react.profiling.min.js
```

I am using windows 10, 64 bit OS, x64-based processor.
Node version: 12.13.0
Yarn Version: 1.22.17

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: copy of [ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-what-is-enospc-error-and-how-to-solve)?

Comment: Sorry, did not get it, could you please explain

Comment: I think it has something to do with the temp folder having too much data and running out of space. If that didn't work, I don't know how to help. Sorry

Comment: I have got below answer:Run the below command to avoid ENOSPC:

echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
But could not run the command in windows, Could you please help me how I can run the command

Comment: @Dolimight `/proc` does not exist on a Windows system