# (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yo

I am new to all the packets (Yo, Bower, Grunt etc), so I decided to follow the Yeoman tutorial step by step http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html, however after installing everything and running grunt serve, I get this:

> (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
>
> (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
>
> (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
>
> node.js:0
>
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I know in the Grunt official site they said that could be due to an alias task with the same name as one of your regular tasks, bu I have the original files created by grunt, yo, node and angular generator, don't seem to be that, anyone can help??

Platform:

yo - 1.4.1

bower - 1.3.12

grunt-cli - v0.1.13

grunt - v0.4.5

node - v0.10.35

npm - 2.1.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this solution worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04: [grunt throw “Recursive process.nextTick detected”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17437601/2747568)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a maximum call issue when running grunt serve, therefore is recommended to have as many windows and programs(e.g.skype, dropbox,sublime, etc) close on your machine

Answer (score 0):

Please try  npm cache clean && npm install gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin ,you can see current   npm versoin and required versoin also then 
 upgrade your npm versoin using this npm install -g npm@latest