# Angular 2 quickstart ENOSPC error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm trying out the official [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) about angular 2 for Typescript. I followed all steps and when I run `npm start` it did pop up the expected `My First Angular 2 App` message on my firefox browser.

However, when I checked the console, I found error messages:

```
Error: watch node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/common/directives/ng_if.js ENOSPC
```

I don't know if it's related to the warning message I received earlier when I run `npm install` on the root folder of the project:

```
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong my approach? A more detailed console output looks like this:

```
> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart
> concurrent "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 

[0] 
[0] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc:w /home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart
[0] > tsc -w
[0] 
[1] 
[1] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite /home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart
[1] > lite-server
[1] 
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  ----------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://10.0.0.17:3000
[1]  ----------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://10.0.0.17:3001
[1]  ----------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:48 304 GET /./index.html (Unknown - 59ms)
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:49 304 GET /node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js (Unknown - 729ms)
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:49 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js (Unknown - 205ms)
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:49 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js (Unknown - 204ms)
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:49 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js (Unknown - 204ms)
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:49 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js (Unknown - 204ms)
[0] 8:14:50 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] [BS] File changed: app/app.component.js
[1] [BS] File changed: app/boot.js
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:51 200 GET /app/boot.js (Unknown - 92ms)
[1] 15.12.19 08:14:52 200 GET /app/app.component.js (Unknown - 29ms)
[1] events.js:141
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1] 
[1] Error: watch node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/common/directives/ng_if.js ENOSPC
[1]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
[1]     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)
[1]     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)
[1]     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
[1]     at setFsWatchListener (/home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
[1]     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
[1]     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
[1]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
[1] 
[1] npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-41-generic
[1] npm 
[1] ERR! argv "/opt/node-v5.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/node-v5.3.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
[1] npm ERR! node v5.3.0
[1] npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
[1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR! 
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
[1] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[1] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
[1] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[1] npm ERR!
[1]  Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[1] npm ERR!     lite-server
[1] npm ERR! You can get their info via:
[1] npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] 
[1] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[1] npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/jsProjects/angular2-quickstart/npm-debug.log
[1] npm run lite exited with code 1
```

Comment: Is your disk full? Does the user have correct permissions to write where he needs to write?

Comment: @m90 No it's not full, and I do have the permission to write in the project folder.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc

Comment: Furthermore this is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31926452

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I resolved this by increasing the amount of inotify watchers :

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: This definitely fix the issue of `ENOSPC` when running `npm start` on the angular 2 tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), Thank you Tomek for sharing!

Comment: Why are there so many dependencies?  There's 374 directories in the node_modules folder for a simple 'hello world' project, which seems vulgarly excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of space. When your installing packages, your disc can nolonger accomodate them thus the error. Solution to to shift the project to a location with more space or add space to the current location.

This is what I did in my case to resolve this error.

Answer (score -1):

This error can also occur during other processes (for example, the more modern `ng serve`).

Although it should be avoided if you do not trust the code, running the command with `sudo` will quickly fix this error.

Comment: It is ad to grant sudo to such at risk command, due to the almost infinite diversity of source code origin that can be ran through npm dependencies.