# Grunt watch fails with message " Running "watch" task Waiting... Warning: Maximum call stack size exceeded "

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have the next Gruntfile.js

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    
    'use strict';

    // Load Grunt tasks declared in the package.json file
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // Configure Grunt
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Grunt express - our webserver
        // https://github.com/blai/grunt-express
        express: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    bases: 'xxxxxxxx',
                    port: 9000,
                    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        // grunt-watch will monitor the projects files
        // https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch
        watch: {
            all: {
                    files: ['**/*.html'],
                    options: {
                        livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        // grunt-open will open your browser at the project's URL
        // https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-open
        open: {
            all: {
                path: 'http://localhost:9000/index.html'
            }
        },

        // grunt-open will install the bower components defined on the bower.json file
        // https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-install-simple
        'bower-install-simple': {
            options: {
                color: true,
                directory: 'assets/bower_components'
            },
            'prod': {
                options: {
                    production: true
                }
            },
            'dev': {
                options: {
                    production: false
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Creates the `server` task
    grunt.registerTask('server', [
        'express',
        'open',
        'watch'
        ]);
};
```

```js
{
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-bower-install-simple": "~1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "matchdep": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-express": "~1.4.1",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.3"
  }
}
```

I try the solution in: [Grunt watch error - Waiting...Fatal error: watch ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc)

but I still have this error:

> Running "watch" task Waiting... Warning: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded

Did anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Which grunt task are you running to get the error? Do you have other tasks you edited out or is this really your full gruntfile?

Comment: I am running grunt server, this is the full gruntfile, thanks

Comment: ok - could you also post your package.json please?

Comment: sure, I add it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc of `grunt-express`, it seems setting `livereload` generates a watch task. I believe this task is conflicting with your own `watch` task.

Try removing your watch config and amending your server task to keep the server alive:

```
// Creates the `server` task
grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'express',
    'open',
    'express-keepalive'
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you SO much, this fix the task!