# Angular2 unhandled 'error' event

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, angular

Im building a dashboard in angular 2 with ts on ubuntu 15.something but,

Im getting a npm error while compiling using npm start in the retail-dashboard folder where my typings and node-modules are located. It will open a webpage but it loads nothing error conn refused

Im at a halt right now and have no clue what to do

npm-debug.log

```
`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'lite' ]
2 info using npm@3.6.0
3 info using node@v5.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelite', 'lite', 'postlite' ]
5 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~prelite: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~prelite: no script for prelite, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/timothy/Dev/retail-dashboard/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/timothy/Dev/retail-dashboard/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
10 verbose lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: CWD: /home/timothy/Dev/retail-dashboard
11 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Args: [ '-c', 'lite-server' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~lite: Failed to exec lite script
14 verbose stack Error: angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular2-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/timothy/Dev/retail-dashboard
17 error Linux 4.2.0-27-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
19 error node v5.6.0
20 error npm  v3.6.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     lite-server
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got it working by issuing the following command:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc), the system has a limit to how many files can be watched by a user. Apparently you can run out of watches. This command increases the maximum amount of watches a user can have.

I first found the solution [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/35), and then followed the trace to the stackoverflow post.

Hope it helps!