# Angular 2 — Error occured when executing command: lite-server

Tags: angular, npm, zsh, oh-my-zsh, lite-server

I have this machine that I install Zsh and OhMyZsh and then I uninstalled them.

Now when I run "npm start" on the [Angular 2 Quick Starter template](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) it give me back this error:

```
Error occured when executing command: lite-server
 Error: spawn /usr/bin/zsh ENOENT
     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
     at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
 Error occured when executing command: lite-server
 Error: spawn /usr/bin/zsh ENOENT
     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
     at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
[1] lite-server exited with code -2

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/hos4m/Workspace/angular2-spotify/npm-debug.log
```

From that second line of the errors stack, I can see that there is a problem with Zsh but I couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the suggestion from this article on similar issue: [Angular2 QuickStart npm start is not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335340/angular2-quickstart-npm-start-is-not-working-correctly)

It says to try changing the start in package.json from

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

to:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: See if your dependencies are up to date. Run 'npm outdated' and then 'npm update'. CC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016905/angular2-quickstart-lite-server-crashes?rq=1

Comment: The packages are up to date. I deleted the "node_modules" folder and run "npm install"

Answer (score 0):

Try

Open 2 instances of cmd at your quickstart dir:

Window 1#
npm run build: watch

then....

window 2#
npm run serve

It will open browser window and run the application

## AngularJS2 npm start Error message