# Gulp Error: watch ENOSPC

Tags: less, browserify, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

Hi i'm getting this error while running gulp watch. im using **vueify** in laravel project.  why is this happening. it was working fine all these days and this came in today.

```
$ gulp watch  
[12:56:01] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/web_projects/next-home/gulpfile.js  
[12:56:01] Starting 'watch'...  
[12:56:01] Starting 'browserify'...  
Fetching Browserify Source Files...  
    - resources/assets/js/app.js  
Saving To...  
   - public/js/app.js  
[12:56:02] Finished 'browserify' after 707 ms  
[12:56:02] 'watch' errored after 722 ms  
[12:56:02] Error: watch /home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/resources/assets/less/ ENOSPC  
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)  
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)  
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)  
    at Gaze._watchDir (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:289:30)  
    at /home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:358:10
    at iterate (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)  
    at Object.forEachSeries (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:66:3)  
    at Gaze._initWatched (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:354:10)  
    at Gaze.add (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:177:8)  
    at new Gaze (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:74:10)  
events.js:154  
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
      ^  
Error: watch /home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/package.json ENOSPC  
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)  
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1313:19)  
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1341:11)  
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)  
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)  
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)  
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)  
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/bazi/Documents/web_projects/next-home/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)  
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

and this is my gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less');
    mix.browserify('app.js');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grunt watch error - Waiting...Fatal error: watch ENOSPC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc)

Answer (score 19):

From http://www.samundra.com.np/solved-gulp-watch-error-enospc/1386
Try this:
Why this issue occured? There is the limit in the number of files that can be watched in a system. We have to increase this number. The below command can be used to increase this number.

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Related Links
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/217

It worked for me. Or decrease the number of files your watcher needs to watch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase your number of watched files in your system config. Run this command and it will work for you

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```