# React create app hot reload is not always working on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, create-react-app

I created a react application using create-react-app boilerplate, which seems to be very popular, hot reload some times updates when any of the files changes and some times not, seems like there is a minimum duration or something like that, I'm using Ubuntu, node version 7.0, the script in package.json is `npm:'react-script start'` what I am missing ?

Comment: Are you using any IDE or launching it direct from console?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia command line, I used react-script start..

Comment: I mean how you edit and manage your project files, maybe a typo is causing react to don't update. Fix code errors and it will reload.

Comment: mmm I don't think so.. it some times work normally... and then stops.. and then works... has not rules...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When npm start doesn’t detect changes, below are the common troubleshooting steps provided in the `create-react-app` documentation - [link](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-start-doesnt-detect-changes).

While an app is running with `npm start` and updating code in the editor should possibly refresh the broswer with the updated code.
If this doesn’t happen, try one of the following workarounds:

1. If the project files are directly synced to your local system from a cloud storage like Dropbox or Google Drive and you're trying to run the app in them directly, try moving it out.
2. Due to Webpack bug, you may [need to restart the watcher](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1164). If the watcher doesn’t detect the index.js and you’re referencing it by the folder name.
3. **Safe write** feature in editors like Vim and IntelliJ currently breaks the watcher. You will need to [disable it](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#adjusting-your-text-editor).
4. Due to [Webpack watcher bug](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/42), projects with path contains parentheses causes issue, try moving the project to a path without them.  .
5. To allow more watchers in Linux and macOS, you might need to [tweak system settings](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#not-enough-watchers).
6. If the project runs inside a virtual machine such as (a Vagrant provisioned) VirtualBox, create an `.env` file in your project directory if it doesn’t exist, and add `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to it. This ensures that the next time you run `npm start`, the watcher uses the polling mode, as necessary inside a VM.
7. Could try increasing `max_users_watches`- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc)

More references:

- [Issue Tracker 1](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/659)
- [Troubleshooting webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#watching)
- [Issue Tracker 2 - Webpack polling](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1049)

Comment: Increasing max_users_watches  works great when suddenly hot reload stops working without a reason.

Comment: It was 6. for me, that solution works for virtual box(what I'm using), thanks!

Comment: Ah. Option 6 was my problem also.

Comment: I'm using windows subsystem for Linux (WSL 2) and the 6 worked for me

Answer (score 12):

Try these:

- Turn off safe write in your IDE
- Increase `max_user_watches`
- Your path should not have parentheses

as last resort try to use this as your env variable:
`CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm start`

Sources:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/659
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1049#issuecomment-261731734

Comment: you even can not imagine how many hours I have tryed to fix hot reload... only your answer had helped, thank you a lot! you are my God)

Comment: No luck with all other workarounds, but your last resort worked. 
My environment is Ubuntu, VS Code, CRA.

Comment: the last CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING env variable have done the trick for me but it slow down my vm drastically. Any clues on that ?

Comment: the CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true does the trick for you consider using another env variable CHOKIDAR_INTERVAL=2000 . This limits the amount of CPU used by CHOKIDAR polling method

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make this work using:

```
sudo npm start
```

Comment: Didnt work for me but `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm start` did. WSL Ubuntu 20

Comment: never run command with sudo unless it really needs super user permission.

Answer (score 5):

run this command

```
sudo -i
echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the node_modules folder and reinstall
by using cmd `npm install`

worked for me ( ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS )

Comment: This worked for me when switching from Hyper Terminal to Kitty in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

In **unbuntu**, i basically kill all the process running on port (for react app default is :3000).

List all the process running on port 3000.

`lsof -i :3000`

This command will show something like this.

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node     7429 yipl   19u  IPv4 1081760      0t0  TCP localhost:3000->localhost:35762 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome  26448 yipl  177u  IPv4 1080082      0t0  TCP localhost:35762->localhost:3000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Now kill the process by PID.

```
kill -9 7429
kill -9 26488
```

Start your react app again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently hot module reloading only works out-of-the-box if you **eject your app**.

But **if you haven't ejected** your app, then you can follow [these instructions](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2317) to get it working.

Find the `ReactDOM.render(...)` at the top of your app, and add these lines below it:

```
ReactDOM.render(...);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    // --- Copy-paste your usual ReactDOM.render(...) call here: --- //
    ReactDOM.render(...);
  });
}
```

The instructions linked above also show how to hot reload things outside of the component tree, such as redux reducers.

Answer (score 0):

One additional case I just experience is when using multiple version of nodejs with NVM in parallel. Basically, I have two terminal windows, one run node 10.x, other on node 9.x, and Webpack watcher stops seeing change.

The solution is to bring both to the same node version

Answer (score 0):

`sudo npm start`

i dont know more about linux, but it is probably due to firewall settings, as i have done the same in windows and there to start react dev server we need to give the access through firewall, so to do the same here we need to give it the admin permision(sudo in case of a ubuntu linux distribution).

Answer (score 0):

If you start your app with a bunch of errors it seems to stop watching your files and thus will not detect your fixes to the broken files. It seems as if you need to initiate "start" with not too many/severe errors for the file watcher to work.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution,

Hope this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76309632/8243241

need to add react-error-overlay v6.0.9

and add this to package.json below the dependencies "resolutions": { "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9" },