# Why won't changes that I've made on a github repo reflect on the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-bootstrap

To start things off, I've successfully git cloned and ran this repo on my machine (https://github.com/creativetimofficial/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react).

At first it didn't work because I didn't run `npm install --save-dev node-sass-chokidar` but again, I can run it successfully on my machine after doing so.

When I run `npm start`, the dashboard and contents appear just fine but upon making any changes to it, like changing some text, it doesn't reflect on the browser at all.  It doesn't even auto-reload which's what it's supposed to do.  Even if I manually press `cmd + r` and/or `cmd + shift + r`, nothing changes.

What could possibly be wrong and how can I rectify this?

Comment: did you restart the app after making changes?

Comment: @schu34 By that, do you mean closing the project then opening it again?  If so, then yes I have.

Comment: Have you run `npm start` again since making your edits?

Comment: @schu34 yes I have but it just asks me if I want to run the project on another port other than 3000

Comment: [Any use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014924/react-create-app-hot-reload-is-not-always-working-on-linux)?

Comment: @Andy Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I see the problem. You have to re-run your app. The fact that you're being asked if you want to run on a different port means the original application (the one without your changes) is still running. In the terminal where you originally ran `npm start` use `ctrl-c` to exit the server and then `npm start` again and you should see your changes reflected.

Comment: hmm, it looks like my changes are indeed reflected when updating some text in a component in the project, for example the `Dashboard.jsx` component.  However, if I try to update text in `tutorial-components.html`, then nothing changes.  Even if I comment the entire `tutorial-components.html` out, it still appears in the browser like  nothing happened.

Comment: `tutorial-components.html` is in the Documentation folder so it probably isn't being run with `npm start` are you able to see your changes when you update things in the `public` and `src` folders?