# How to prevent Unhandled 'error' event when starting lite-server?

Tags: angular, lite-server

I install lite-server using:

```
npm install lite-server
```

But it generates the message bellow:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

And if run:

```
npm run lite-server
```

It gives me this error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch web_app/node_modules/babel-generator/node_modules/lodash/isObject.js ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1429:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1456:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/var/www/html/web_app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/var/www/html/web_app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/var/www/html/web_app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/var/www/html/web_app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/web_app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

I found this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2692, but I doesn't solve my problem.

Is there anyone who met this problem before, and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several research, I came across with [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc):

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

I still don't know why I need to do this, but it works. ;)