# When I use ionic serve in ionic 2 project this error appears. How do I solve this?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I found this Error, I am using ionic 2 angular 2. Whenever use the (ionic serve) command I found this error.
How do I solve this?

```
periyasamy@LAP-**5CG6326ZB7** ~/ionic_works $ cd sampleApp/
periyasamy@LAP-5CG6326ZB7 ~/ionic_works/sampleApp $ ionic serve
ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp
ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

[17:10:26]  ionic-app-scripts 1.1.3 
[17:10:26]  watch started ... 
[17:10:26]  build dev started ... 
[17:10:26]  clean started ... 
[17:10:26]  clean finished in 1 ms 
[17:10:26]  copy started ... 
[17:10:26]  transpile started ... 
[17:10:28]  transpile finished in 2.13 s 
[17:10:28]  preprocess started ... 
[17:10:28]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[17:10:28]  webpack started ... 
[17:10:28]  copy finished in 2.27 s 
[17:10:34]  webpack finished in 6.23 s 
[17:10:34]  sass started ... 
[17:10:35]  sass finished in 895 ms 
[17:10:35]  postprocess started ... 
[17:10:35]  postprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[17:10:35]  lint started ... 
[17:10:35]  build dev finished in 9.31 s 
[17:10:35]  **watch failed: watcher error:** 
        /home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/src/assets/**/*,/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/src/index.html,/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/src/manifest.json,/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/src/service-worker.js,/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*,/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*,/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js,/home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js:
        **# Error: watch /home/periyasamy/ionic_works/sampleApp/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts ENOSPC**
```

[17:10:35]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[17:10:36]  lint finished in 1.19 s

> *****Ionic Info***** periyasamy@LAP-5CG6326ZB7 ~/ionic_works/sampleApp $ ionic info
>
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: 6.5.0  Ionic Framework Version: 2.1.0 Ionic CLI Version:
>    2.2.1 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0 Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.3 ios-deploy version: Not installed ios-sim version: Not installed OS: 
>   Linux 4.4 Node Version: v6.10.0 Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: `ENOSPC` means that there is no space on the drive. Did you checked the available space?

Comment: I had the same issue and enough space left. And this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If your npm is already update (check it by **npm -v** it must be above 2.0) then run this command on your terminal -

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```