# Nuxt.js Vue error in installing

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue.js

I install nux.js but it give me error. I also update my npm to 5.5.1 .
I dont know how to fix it. any one encounter this error?
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/

**error**

```
Error: watch /home/laravel/Sites/kenneth/nuxt.config.js ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1383:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1409:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/laravel/Sites/kenneth/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/laravel/Sites/kenneth/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/laravel/Sites/kenneth/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/laravel/Sites/kenneth/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/laravel/Sites/kenneth/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! kenneth@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the kenneth@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/laravel/.npm/_logs/2017-10-25T04_42_50_296Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.JS Error: ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research found the solution. Run the below command.

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

credit to : [Grunt watch error - Waiting...Fatal error: watch ENOSPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748737/grunt-watch-error-waiting-fatal-error-watch-enospc/31926452#31926452)